# how to pass a value to the bitfield

Tags: c, indexing

I don't know how to pass a value to the bitfield:

- in header file I have the struct definition below:

```
typedef struct { boolean Error; } Struct_A_T;

Struct_A_T Struct_A = {0U};
boolean WriteValue;

if (TRUE) {
  Struct_A.Error.index = WriteValue;
}
}
else {
  index++;
}
```

As you can see, the index will increment, I want the WriteValue to pass a value to the bit location equal to index for Struct_A_Error. I don't know how should I define this and make the bit as flexible so index can control the bit location. Thanks

expect to have bit location update to the value of index

Comment: hey, there's syntactical errors in your code, and you have put things outside of a function that need to go inside of a function. So, I'm afraid we have to *guess* what you mean. That's not an option – please fix the code you paste so that it actually compiles.

Comment: Your posted code is unclear. For example, there opening `{` and closing `}` braces are mismatched.

Comment: You've not shown the definition of `bookean` but unless it is a structure, there isn't a member `index` in it.  If it is a structure, what does it contain?  There are no bit-fields evident in the code I see.

Comment: Assuming you put the code in a function (vs. at global/file scope--which isn't valid C), try changing `Struct_A.Error.index = WriteValue;` into: `boolean tmp = Struct_A.Error; boolean msk = 1 << index; tmp &= ~msk; if (WriteValue) tmp |= msk; Struct_A.Error = tmp;` I presume you have something like: `typedef unsigned int boolean;` or `typedef unsigned char boolean;` or `typedef int boolean;` somewhere. That is, `boolean` is a simple scalar type of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

> expect to have bit location update to the value of index

That's not how bitfields work. That's impossible in C.

Types in C are static. They can't be changed at runtime – so your bitfield *must* always be in the same position.

If you need to set a specific bit in a memory location, you will have to put an integer there, and use bit shifts and logical operators to put the bit where you want it.

Comment: C supports bit fields in structs by specifying the length in bits after a colon (e.g. `struct { int bf : 2; }` declares a 2 bit signed integer). Almost everything is implementation dependent, so not very useful except in special cases. Also not what the original poster seems to think of as a "bitfield".

Comment: @JohnBayko Bit-fields have another quirk: `int bf : 2;` might declare an unsigned integer.  To get a signed one, code needs `signed int bf : 2;`.  "it is implementation-defined whether the specifier int designates the same type as signed int or the same type as unsigned int." C17 6.7.2

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, OP does not want a bit-field or `bool` `struct` member, yet a simply *unsigned*.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
  unsigned Error;
} Struct_A_T;

Struct_A_T Struct_A = {0U};

...
bool WriteValue;
...
if (TRUE) {
  unsigned mask = 1u << index; 
  if (WriteValue) Struct_A |= mask;
  else Struct_A &= ~mask;
}
...
```

`index` should be less than an `unsigned` bit-width  (typically 32).